# How can I auto refresh my search results using a marker?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, tags, marker

I will post the code here, but basically I have a check box and every time I search I want to refresh the search area when i check and uncheck the marker. How can I go about to do this..

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            jQuery('#allProgram').change(function () {
                var elemnt         
                jQuery('form#AdvancedSearch').find('#allProgram').get(0);
                if (jQuery(this).prop('checked')) {

                    jQuery(elemnt).val(' 
                }
                else {
                    jQuery(elemnt).val('False');
                }
        });
```

Comment: What is elemnt? You don't assign it to anything. You can't set its value if it isn't assigned to anything.

What do you mean by "marker"?

Also, why don't you use $ instead of jQuery? Looks like you pass it in, so you may as well use it to keep the code looking cleaner.

Comment: marker is the checkbox for #allprograms. I want to be able to check and uncheck that but i want the function to relaod the search area.

Answer (score 0):

Man, I wrote a little code to solve your problem. You can test in this URL: http://jsfiddle.net/xxfn1xpx/

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="search">
```

JavaScript:

```
var checkbox = $('input[name="languages"]');
var search = $('#search');

checkbox.on('change', function() {
    result = [];

    checkbox.each(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) { result.push($(this).val()); }
    });

    search.val(result.join(' '));
});
```

I hope I have helped you. Let me know if it help you ;)

Comment: Thank you, I used your code but it did not work, i gave me an error, its basically a search area, and has a button for it to search all programs, so I want to be able to check and uncheck this box and for it to refresh the search, your code did help but when i checked it or unchecked it, it would go back to default checked, it does not stay checked or unchecked,here is the whole code agian ...

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        jQuery('#allProgram').change(function () {
            var elemnt = jQuery('form#AdvancedSearch').find('#allProgram').get(0);
            if (jQuery(this).prop('checked')) {
                jQuery(elemnt).val('True');
            }
            else {

                jQuery(elemnt).val('False');
               
            }
                
           });
        
   WHERE WOULD I BE ABLE TO ENTER YOUR CODE INTO

Comment: hm. can you pull all the code (html and css) in jsfiddle.net?

Comment: sure, here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/o5q28nv1/  that is my search.cshtml javascript code that i need to modify the (allprogram) checkbox